# Different behaviour of Google Earth Engine linked maps in code editor and as a deployed app

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to develop an app utilizing linked maps where geometries are reflected in both maps.
The code works fine as expected in the editor, but when I publish the app, the geometry is not shown on both panels.
The toy example code

```
var map1 = ui.Map();
map1.drawingTools().setLinked(true);

var map2 = ui.Map();
map2.drawingTools().setLinked(true);

ui.Map.Linker([map1, map2]);

ui.root.widgets().reset([ui.SplitPanel({firstPanel: map1, secondPanel: map2})]);
```

The code is available at
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f9ba409b2c434cc850505a05b2c14466
The corresponding published app is at
https://nirdeshksharma.users.earthengine.app/view/fsd